# Calling instance method from XSLT using Saxon-HE 9.6

Tags: java, templates, xslt, saxon

We have a use-case where we have to call instance methods from Xlst template. We are using Saxon-HE 9.6 version. Went though this [stack-overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59390652/how-to-use-xml-transformer-with-java-object-as-parameter). We tried psssing XML transformer with Java object as parameter and then updated the template to call that instance method. But it's giving javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException.

Can some-one please help if we can call instance method from XSLT template using Saxon HE ?

Java Object :

```
public Double getValue(String s1, String s2, Double d1) {
    // perform some operation and call other service to fetch data.
    Double response = 2.0;
    return response;
}
```

Xlst template :
Added :

```
xmlns:util="java:com.test.utils.TestUtils"

<!--<xsl:value-of select="util:getValue($utils, $country1, $country2, $value)"/>
```

Code to pass this util object to xlst

```
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsltTemplate);
transformer.setParameter("utils", util);
```

Comment: You need to use so called *integrated extension functions* if you want to call into Java.

Comment: Documentation is at https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/extensibility/integratedfunctions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this capability is not available in Saxon-HE. There are alternatives: see the section "Extensibility" in the documentation at [www.saxonica.com](http://www.saxonica.com).

Note also that 9.6 is a rather old release. Since Saxon tracked the draft XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 specs as they were developed, it's best to avoid old versions of the product, because the specs were in flux at the time of the product release.